# How to swap two whole activity when button is clicked and when application start again then display that swapping changes

Tags: java, android, android-activity

Basically,I have two activity

1.`FirstActivity.java` and

2.`SecondActivity.java`.

In this `SecondActivity.java`I have one Button that works as swapping between this two activity.So, when I press that Button at that time `SecondActivity.java` activity swapped with `FirstActivity.java` and when I close my application and restart again my application display that swapped operation means `SecondActivity.java` activity swapped successfully with the`FirstActivity.java`.

So,Guys If anyone know how can I do this then give me some idea to Implement this kind of functionality.

Comment: Use shared preference to know about the changes.

Comment: I have added answer below. Please check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your SecondActivity add following lines in onCreate() :

```
SharedPreference pref = getSharedPreferences("yourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
String activityName = pref.getString("activityName",null);

if(activityName != null && activityName.equals("FirstActivity")){
 startActivity(new Intent(this,FirstActivity.class));
 finish();
}
```

In clicklistner of button of SecondActivity.java class add following lines:

```
 SharedPreference pref = getSharedPreferences("yourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
 editor.putString("activityName", "FirstActivity");
 editor.commit();
```

In clicklistener of button of FirstActivity.java class add following lines :

```
 SharedPreference pref = getSharedPreferences("yourPref", MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
 editor.putString("activityName", "SecondActivity");
 editor.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly terminate your application.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

        AlertDialog.Builder al=new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        al.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        al.setMessage(R.string.wanna_exit);
        al.setIcon(R.drawable.back);
        al.setCancelable(false);
        al.setPositiveButton(R.string.yea,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){public void onClick(DialogInterface id, int s){
            moveTaskToBack(true);
            getIntent().removeExtra("isInit");  // remove if you're using any extra
            android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
            finish();
            System.exit(1);
        }});
        al.setNegativeButton(R.string.nope,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){public void onClick(DialogInterface id, int s){id.cancel();}});
        al.create().show();
 }
```

Use `finish()` when you want to move from one activity to another.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
     Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstActivity.class);
     startActivity(intent);
     finish();
}
```

Comment: Thxx for your response...i will try this solution

Answer (score 0):

Lets make some order here.
"switching" activities is a very confusing expression to say.
I would suggest you that when the user click the button at one of those activities you will save a number in `Intent`.

> For example:
>
> 0 - open the first activity.
>
> 1 - open the second activity.

I'm guessing your app is launching from the first activity.

When the application first run, retrieve this number from the `Inent`.
If its a `0` do nothing.
If its a `1`- use: `startActivity(new Intent(FirstActivity.this, SecondActivity.class))` to start the 2nd activity and right after, use `finish()` to close `FirstActivity`